# Repetitive Multiplication/Division

Tags: algorithms

I have a number **x** = 10000 (for example), I want to divide it by a number **y** = 1.2 (for example) continuously until the result is equal or less than 1.

for example:

```
10000 / 1.2 = 8333.333
8333.333 / 1.2 = 6944.444
6944.444 / 1.2 = 5787.037
...etc
```

.

**The question is:**

Is there a way to find **how many divisions** occur until we reach the "**1**" without actually going through all of them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume $x$ and $y$ are greater than $1$. You want to find an integer $n$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{y} < \frac{x}{y^n} \leq 1.
$$
We can rewrite this inequality as
$$
y^{n-1} < x \leq y^n.
$$
Now take logarithms and divide by $\log y$:
$$
n-1 < \frac{\log x}{\log y} \leq n.
$$
It follows that
$$
n = \bigg\lceil\frac{\log x}{\log y}\bigg\rceil,
$$
where $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ is the [ceiling function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceiling_function).

Comment: Great solution! Thank you.